# Create a for loop to fill month after every row in Excel

Tags: excel

How would you create a for loop in excel that would extract the month in column "Month" after entering the date in the 1st column? 
I have gotten the formula to enter in the cell to extract the month for that specified row in the 1st column with:

Formula for extracting the month: =IF(A61="","",TEXT(A61,"mmmmmmmm"))

Formula for extracting the year: =IF(A61="","yyyy",YEAR(A61))

Please change the highlighted portion to match the row number where the cells are.

However, what if in row 403, I type 8-Jun-20, for example; I would like the 4th column of row 403 to automatically fill Jun, without entering the above formula.

[image]

Comment: Make your data a table with `Ctrl+T` and the formula should populate downwards automatically.

Comment: Table is best. You could drag your formulas to go down further (say to the 500th row) but that's rather sloppy. You could also do this in VBA with a change event